# How to remove character from string without any built in method in Java neither I want to use stringbuilder or string buffer

Tags: java, string

Can anyone tell me how to remove character from string without any use of built-in functions and stringbuffer or builder. Although I tried to form a logic but didn't get the answer. As in below code I want to remove 'he' from the inputstring.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class p1 {
    public static void main(String[] rgs) {
        System.out.println("enter the string");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System. in );
        String str = s.nextLine();
        p1 g = new p1();
        g.replacechar(str);
    }
    public void replacechar(String str) {
        String e = "";
        int l = str.length();
        char ch[] = str.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (ch[i] == 'h' && ch[i + 1] == 'e') {
                ch[i] = ' ';
                ch[i + 1] = ' ';
                e += ch[i];
            } else {
                System.out.println("no ");
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW you used built-in API `toCharArray()`

Comment: Please make your question readable by ... 1) Use uppercase letters at beginning of sentences (and wherever appropriate, too). 2) Format your code to make it read nicely. Now it has way too many empty lines.

Comment: Well, Strings are *immutable* in Java, so you will effectively be creating a new String (unless you break *immutability* via *reflection*). You will need atleast some built-in functions

Comment: Your code currently uses `if`, `System.out.println`... and others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but may be what you want is(just modified your code) :

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < ch.length ; i++)
{
    if (ch[i] == 'h' && ch[i+1] == 'e')
    {
       ch[i] = ' ';
       ch[i + 1] = ' ';
       i = i +2;
    }
    else
    {
       e +=ch[i];
    }
}
```

Input : "My he is"

Output : "My is"

Comment: thnxx ..got solution :)

Answer (score 1):

With not using any build in function.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class replacechar {
       String line;
       String s = "";
       char from ;
       char to ;
       public replacechar()
       {
           Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Enter The String");
           line = scan.nextLine();
           System.out.println("Enter The Character you want to changer");
           from = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);
           System.out.println("Enter the Character you want to replace with");
           to = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);
           replacecharacter(from,to);
       }
       public void replacecharacter(char f,char t)
       {
           for(int i =0;i< line.length();i++)
           {

               if(line.charAt(i) == f)
               {
                  s += t;
               }
               else
               {
                   s += line.charAt(i);
               }

           }
           System.out.println(s);
       }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        replacechar  obj = new replacechar();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this(i have been using this a lot :)):

```
Str.replace('he', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input="my he is";
    String output="";
    String c="he";
    String[] split = input.split(c);
    for(int i=0;i<(split.length);i++)
    {
    output=output.concat(split[i])  ;
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

> split will work fine hr

Answer (score 0):

we can convert a String toCharArray and check current character is which we want to remove or not if the character is not which we want to remove then we will add to the new String else we wont add to the String

```
String str = "hello";
String s = "";
char charToRemove = 'h';
char[]ar = str.toCharArray();
for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++) {
    if(ar[i]!=charToRemove) 
        s+=ar[i];
}   
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it